# Testing for drawnLine touching a moving bitmap on a Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a moving bitmap image on a Canvas and when I touch the lower part of the screen there is one small line drawn which moves up the screen.

How can I test if this moving line is touching the moving image or not?

Example of a collision:

[image]

Comment: How I understand this is that you have a bitmap moving around and when you press the lower part of the screen it sends a "projectile" upwards, and you want to know if it hits the bitmap?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: ya just i want to know how i hit the bitmap image using drawline

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AsmOf.png

Comment: please help me as soon as you can....thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this : [Rectangle.intersects](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#intersects%28android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect%29)

```
boolean isCollision = Rectangle.intersects(rectangle_around_image, rectangle_around_line);
```

You need to call that code when your line and/or image move. But since you didn't post your code it's difficult to help you more.